# SQL Server query include null in where clause

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

I have the table in following format. I am trying to query this table to get all the records which are not PC and PT.

So my query should return ID 3,4,5,6,7 and should ignore 1 and 2

```
    CREATE TABLE #t (ID INT, V VARCHAR(16))

    INSERT  INTO #t
    VALUES  (1, 'PC'),
            (2, 'PT'),
            (3, NULL),
            (4, NULL),
            (5, NULL),
            (6, 'PS'),
            (7, 'PD');

drop table #t
```

The query that I am using is which returns only 6 and 7 and ignores null records in the result set .:

```
select 
    id, v 
from 
    #t 
where  
    v != 'PC' and V != PT
```

Please let me know what should I do in order to include null in my result set?

Comment: Add `OR V IS NULL` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Just use NOT IN ('PC', 'PT'). It will return all the rows except PC and PT

Comment: @PareshJ - `NOT IN ('PC','PT')` will also exclude `NULL` records.

Comment: Yes, it should be not in ('PC','PT') or v is null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query should check null condition as well.

Query -

```
select id , v from #t where  v not in ('PC' , 'PT') OR v is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id , v from #t where  v!='PC' and V!=PT or OR V IS NULL
```

All good. please add the null condition too

or

```
select id , v from #t where  v not in ('PC' , 'PT') and v is null
```

use `not in` It will return all the rows except PC and PT

Comment: the first query works but not the second .Thanks for the feedback

Comment: SELECT ID, V FROM #t WHERE ISNULL(V,'') NOT IN ('PC' , 'PT')

Comment: @ps_prakash02 your query is way better put it as answer or else i will put same aas answer

Comment: The first query won't work - you've got two ORs, and mixing AND and OR in your where clause without the brackets means results will return the wrong results

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `!=` for every condition, use a `not in` and for handling null values, use `isnull`

```
select 
  id, v 
from 
  #t 
where  
  isnull(v,'') not in ('PC', 'PT')
```